# inserting custom type array into table column in postgresql-9.4?

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a custom type "nameage" and a table "namesages".

```
CREATE TYPE nameage AS(
name_ varchar(50),
age smallint 
);
CREATE TABLE namesages(
id serial,
namesandages nameage[]
);

INSERT INTO namesages(namesandages) VALUES(ARRAY[['john', 24],['david', 38]]::nameage[]);
```

Why does this query give error?;

```
ERROR:  malformed record literal: "john"
LINE 1: insert into namesages(namesandages) values(ARRAY[['john', 24...
                                                          ^
DETAIL:  Missing left parenthesis.
********** Error **********
```

Comment: Why don't you properly normalize your data model?

Comment: What is the intent of your two dimensional array? In your current code, you seem to need only a single dimension... Also, please, can you ask one question at a time. It will be much easier and more useful to answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you meant to do was this:

```
INSERT INTO namesages(namesandages) 
VALUES(ARRAY[ROW('john', 24),ROW('david', 38)]::nameage[]);
```

This creates a one dimensional array of user-defined composite types. I'm not sure what you intended to do when you defined a two-dimensional array...